# Keep selected filters from a report to another report in Power BI online

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have two reports, one is kind of a navigation report where we can choose the KPI(Accident statistics for exemple), click on It and we will be directed to Accident page of the second report concerned. The navigation report has a Selection page where we can make a projection of data in a specific perimeter (to select for exemple a coutry). The second report has the same page Selection.

My question is : How can I keep filters selected in the Selection page of the navigation report after being directed to the second report without reselecting the filters on the second report ?

The solution may exist in Power BI Desktop or online, but the manipulation issue is in Power BI online.

Thank you in advance guys !